# CodePilot for Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, plugins, xcode5

Is there any way to use CodePilot on Xcode 5? I'm trying to install but not appears on plugin section.
Anyone knows other similar software for Xcode 5?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodePilot 2.x is only for XCode 4.x, its a requirement, it's indeed not listed in the plugins folder of XCode.app, I also tried by unpacking the archive from the package itself into the plugins folder, it doesn't load in XCode 5.
You could try emailing them regarding compatibility here: codepilot@macoscope.net

Comment: Code Pilot 3.x has been released as open source, it works with XCode 5.x as developers say, here is the project: https://github.com/macoscope/CodePilot